# Transparent AlertDialog Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to make my AlertDialog transparent, the following is my code and the line where it should be transparent just doesnt work.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            AlertDialog alertDialog;

            context = getActivity();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.moreinfotable,null);

            ListView list = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_listView);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    ViewImage.this.getActivity(), R.layout.interior_listview,
                    R.id.interior_list_text, values);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setView(layout);

            alertDialog = builder.create();

//THE LINE THAT DOESNT WORK// alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            alertDialog.show();
```

can someone please help. Thank you.

This is what i want to do.
[image]

Comment: Try set transparent background this layout moreinfotable

Comment: i did, i get is a gray background because of the white alertdialog background which wont go transparent

Comment: Before setting the view try to set the transparency. In one of the endeavours, I wanted to remove the dialog title and just moving the code `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` above the `setView(view)` made the difference.

Comment: What is the background color of your ListView? How about the background color of your dialog button? Is everything but the text supposed to be transparent?

Comment: @JigishChawda : didnt work tried that too..

Comment: @DaneWhite: ive updated my question, this is what i wanna do.

Comment: You might want to post your layout code for R.layout.moreinfotable, it's possible that your window has the correct transparency, but your views don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this way

```
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.argb(0, 200, 200, 200)));
```

I did this on custom alert dialog.

Values are like alpha, red, green, blue. Range from 0 to 255. Change values of alpha to get different degree of transparency

I don't know if this will help you. This is how i created my dialog box (its a prompt to user to try the app without log-in)

```
public void promptUser()
{       
    final Dialog requestDialog= new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
    requestDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    requestDialog.setContentView(R.layout.lyt_prompt_user);

    TextView requestTitle = (TextView) requestDialog.findViewById(R.id.request_title);
    TextView requestText = (TextView) requestDialog.findViewById(R.id.request_text);
    Button acceptButton = (Button) requestDialog.findViewById(R.id.request_accept);
    Button rejectButton = (Button) requestDialog.findViewById(R.id.request_reject);

    requestTitle.setText("Don't want to login?");
    requestText.setText("You can still explore the app with limited functionality.");

    acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // do something
            requestDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    rejectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            requestDialog.dismiss();
            (MyActivity.this).finish();
        }
    });

    requestDialog.setCancelable(false);
    requestDialog.show();
    requestDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.argb(0, 200, 200, 200)));
}
```

I tried changing the alpha from 0 to 90, it shows a faint white background, somewhat glassy feeling.